# Android native window rendering - how to adjust for stride?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to draw into a Surface from native code and can't understand why the stride in my ANativeWindow_Buffer is not "width * 2" for an RGB 565 format?

My window is 533x732 and format is RGB565.  The stride comes back as 544.

I don't get how the stride can be 544 or how I can tweak my buffer of RGB 565 data to account for it.

This is a similar question that was answered but this guy is using Skia which I'm not using: [Native window rendering issue on Samsung Galaxy S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211773/native-window-rendering-issue-on-samsung-galaxy-s3)

Comment: Okay, I see 'stride' here is in PIXELS, not bytes.  Still, I would expect stride to be 533 in this case and not 544.  So now I'm having to waste CPU cycles by copying my RGB data into a buffer and padding for the last 11 pixels in the expected stride.  The image displays correctly now but I'm still confused why stride != width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly common for stride to be a multiple of 16 (or some other power of two) due to hardware limitations.  This is why stride is specified separately.

If you can declare your source buffer to have a stride of 544, you can do a straight copy.